# C++ - Combining Copy/Move operators and constructors

Tags: c++, copy-constructor, move-semantics

As it stands right now, I have a class with the following structure:

```
struct FooClass {

    FooClass();
    FooClass(int CustomIndex);
    FooClass(const FooClass& CopyConstructor);
    FooClass(FooClass&& MoveConstructor);

    FooClass& operator=(const FooClass& CopyAssignment);
    FooClass& operator=(FooClass&& MoveAssignment);
};
```

Is there any way for me to combine the copy/move operators so that they don't need to be provided in the first place and copy/move constructors would be called instead?

if not, is it at least possible for me to call the copy/move constructor from the copy/move operator?

Essentially, I want:

`FooClass(const FooClass& CopyConstructor)` to equal to `FooClass& operator=(const FooClass& CopyAssignment)`

and

`FooClass(FooClass&& MoveConstructor)` to equal to `FooClass& operator=(FooClass&& MoveAssignment)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mean like

```
FooClass& operator=(FooClass rhs)
{
    swap(rhs);
    return *this;
}
```

where `rhs` is constructed with either the copy- or the move-constructor? (Given you provide `swap`, which is a good idea in general)

---

After you updated the question, maybe this works for you:

```
FooClass(const FooClass& CopyConstructor)
{
    *this = CopyConstructor;
}

FooClass(FooClass&& MoveConstructor)
{
    *this = std::move(MoveConstructor);
}
```

Comment: I need to copy/move separate because the logic is very different for copy and move operators. I am trying to get copy constructor function same as copy operator and move constructor function same as move operator.

Comment: @Grapes In that case I don't understand your question. Can you edit and clarify?

Comment: Can I write move constructor in such a way where I don't need a move operator? And the move operator would be generated by the compiler, but still call the move constructor? I just don't want to duplicate move functionality in BOTH move operator AND move constructor.

Comment: @Grapes I updated the answer, since you said in the Q that you want the constructor to use the assignment. But in other places you say it the other way round.

Comment: Sorry, it was difficult to formulate my question, but that second part solves my question.

Answer (score 0):

If your class is trivial (you only have primitive types and STL objects) very likely the default implementation just works. Don't bother writing these down, they will be there by default. The copy and move will be done member by member using the respective copy move constructors.

If you have something special inside (some unmovable class for example) then you need to define these, but you can still delegate the implementation to one another or to another method.

Comment: How do I "can still delegate the implementation to one another"?